# Sending a request in the background and when the application is unloaded from memory

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

Is it possible to implement a solution where files would sent in the background to the server in iOS? Or when the application memory is unloaded?

I us `URLSession` and its `background(withIdentifier:)` method.

When the application is active or minimized, but visible on the screen, the request completes successfully. If you hide the application, but leave it in the background, or close it completely, an error is triggered:

> "Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Connection to Background File Transfer Service Lost" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "BackgroundDataTask <94E37A0C-F58D-4EC3-B69D-311F3D57B813>.<4>",
> "LocalDataTask <94E37A0C-F58D-4EC3-B69D-311F3D57B813>.<4>"
> ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundDataTask <94E37A0C-F58D-4EC3-B69D-311F3D57B813>.<4>, NSLocalizedDescription=Lost connection to Background File Transfer Service}
> Thread <NSThread: 0x6000013ff040>{number = 10, name = (null)}
> error"

**Signing & Capabilities Setup**

[image: Signing & Capabilities Setup]

In my knowledge, on Android there is a `WorkManager`. Is it possible to implement something similar if I need to send about 10-30 photos no larger than 50 mb?

This is my implementation that was not successful.

```swift
class DataProvider: NSObject {

  func sendPostRequestInBackground() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")!
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
      "title": "My Title",
      "body": "Hello, World!",
      "userId": 1
    ]

    do {
      let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
      request.httpBody = jsonData
    } catch {
      print("Error creating JSON data: \(error)")
    }

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "test.HelloWorld")
    configuration.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true

    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    task.earliestBeginDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(10)
    task.resume()
  }
}

extension DataProvider: URLSessionTaskDelegate {

  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
      print("Error")
    } else {
      print("POST successfully")
    }
  }

  func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
              let completionHandler = appDelegate.bgSessionCompletionHandler
      else { return }

      appDelegate.bgSessionCompletionHandler = nil
      completionHandler()
    }
  }
}

@main
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var bgSessionCompletionHandler:(() ->())?

  func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String,
    completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
  ) {
    bgSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Did you activate the capability for background activity in XCodeProject → Signing & Capabilities → + Capability (top left) →  Background modes → background processing and background fetch?